# Vaadin Scroll to component like html anchor -> UI.getCurrent().scrollIntoView(component)

Tags: scroll, anchor, vaadin

I'm trying to scroll to a component like an html anchor does. The method `UI.getCurrent().scrollIntoView(component)` scrolls to the right component. But the component is shown at the bottom. I would like to show it at the top (line an html anchor does). Is there a way to do this in vaadin?

GWT has the component Anchor. But it is not availble in vaadin. Any idea?

Comment: did you find a solution for this yet? I was just able to find out that `scrollIntoView(component)` scrolls to the center of the `component`